# Url rewrite dont work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

We have a multi-domain web site; many "websites" in the same web application.
And we want to rewrite url to "www.*" style. It´s simple when you do that site per site:

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical host name">
      <match url="^(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mydomainTest\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomainTest.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But we have some problems when try a "canonical" regex for any host name:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Canonical host name">
        <match url="^(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([www.]{0,4})([A-Za-z0-9]*)(.com)([.ar]{0,3})$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{R:2}.com{R:4}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

We do tests in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/#) and we regex do that:

regex = `^([www.]{0,4})([A-Za-z0-9]*)(.com)([.ar]{0,3})$`

1)
domain test = "www.mydomainTest.com.ar"
result =

```
   {R:1} = www.
   {R:2} = mydomainTest
   {R:3} = .com
   {R:4} = .ar
```

[image: Test 1 www.mydomainText.com.ar]

2)
domain test = mydomainTest.com.ar
result =

```
   {R:1} = 
   {R:2} = mydomainTest
   {R:3} = .com
   {R:4} = .ar
```

[image: Test 2 mydomainText.com.ar]

The same result with "URL Rewrite 2.0" in iis 7.

We can be sure the regex is working ok, but our webswite DON´T rewrite as expected. If you access to "www.domain.com.ar" or "domain.com.ar" is the same, nothing happend. But if you use the first rewrite configuration all worked fine.
I hope I have been clear explaining the problem.

Well, what are we forget? what we have done wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The second rule will not work because the {R:2} and {R:4} values are null. The pattern it is trying to match is ^(.*) which will give you only {R:0} and {R:1}.

Comment: If i don´t use "<match url="^(.*)" />" it should work?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you're negating the condition, so your variables will not exist...

Give this a try

```xml
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Canonical host name" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}"  appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```